# Can "da" phrase endings used in Russian and Kannada be traced back to the same origin (as in usage, not like cognates)?

Tags: historical-linguistics, russian, slang

Example: *Can you get me a coffee da* , *get off the computer, da* even *just give me a name, da* in Kannada English code switched sentence. And Cosmo in Gaurdians of the Galaxy new Comic series can give one examples for Russian.

Comment: The Russian question tag da is transparent (deriving from the Russian word for "yes"). What is the internal etymology of the Kannada *da*? I cannot imagine a common origin with one exception: It is a recent loan from Russian, e.g., the habit was acquired by communist students studying in Russia.

Comment: Kannada _da_ looks like just a slang ending for me, like _bruv_ endings in U.K. English, that is just there to increase the _camaraderie_ feeling maybe...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely not. Its similar to asking if Kannada word *alla*, which is a negation suffix and also a separate word for no/not, is same as the Islamic deity. It's just coincidence. They are false friends.

This *da* phrase ending, which sort of replaces *dude* in English, is actually a suffix and it is not of Kannada origin. It is of Tamil origin and it is a bona fide suffix in that language. This suffix is mostly used in English (and never Kannada) spoken in Bangalore, a city right at the border with the neighboring state of Tamil Nadu where Tamil is spoken. There is a long history of Tamil migration to Bangalore but this suffix is a recent thing and only a few decades old. You might also hear *ra* used, which is a Telugu origin suffix serving the same purpose. I grew up using *man* and still use it.

Furthermore, it is one of the aspects of Indian English. The general North Indian variation is to use the word *yaar*, which means friend in Persian, and consequently in Hindi, Urdu etc.

*What's up da = What's up yaar*

Answer (score 1):

The origin and roles are different since [Kannada is a Dravidian language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada), not a relative of the Japanese or Basque, while Russian makes a part of the Slavic branch within the Indo-European family.

The role of the Russian word is a particle (connecting sentence parts) or 'yes'-word, or an intensifier related either to a pronoun or, which I beleibe to be more realistic, a verb meaning 'to give'.

The Kannada word ಡಾ, as the dictionaries say, is an abbreviation for 'doctor', which by itself in English could be traced back to a Proto Indo-European verb meaning 'to take'. A theory of Dravidian-IE philum seems to lack any sustainable proof.

The first traces of proto-Kannada, as the Wikipedia puts it, could be traced back to 500 B. C., the times when the very existence of any Slavic language and/or nation is less than questionable.

Therefore, my answer is negative.

Comment: Oh wait oh no, I will edit my question, really sorry

Comment: Edit done! Check out

Comment: @WiccanKarnak That didn't change much about my reply.

Comment: Nope not the doctor _da_ , the slang _da_

Comment: *500 B. C., the times when the very existence of any Slavic language and/or nation is less than questionable.*  The proto-Slavic language existed then.  It did not drop from the moon.

Comment: The Proto-Slavic existed around early 100s A.D., not earlier.

Comment: @Manjusri, "The Proto-Slavic existed around early 100s A.D., not earlier." really? How do you know this?